# JavaCV AndroidFrameConverter converted Bitmap imperfect on saving to local storage

Tags: android, javacv

I am trying to convert a byte array of image data into a bitmap using Android frame converter as shown below:

```
((ByteBuffer) frame.image[0].position(0)).put(event.getImageData());// frame is a javacv frame.
backCamFilter.push(frame); //FFmpegFrameFilter
pulledFrame = backCamFilter.pull();
byte[] data = ((ByteBuffer)pulledFrame.image[0].position(0)).array();
Frame convertedFrame = converter.convert(data, 480, 480);//AndroidFrameConverter
Bitmap bitmap = converter.convert(convertedFrame);
if (bitmap != null) {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Constants.COVER_IMAGE_FOLDER + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, outputStream);
    Log.d(TAG, "writeCoverImage: " + count);
}
```

The above code generates the image added below, as you can see the left portion of the image contains a part of the right part of the image. Does any of you guys know why this happens or any alternative solutions?

I also tried converting the 'pulledFrame' directly into bitmap but its giving me "RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels".

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am getting the similar issue and stuck.

Comment: I cropped the left portion of the image.